# My regex does not match with the "[" and "]" character despite escaping them for Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

may I know why my Regex does not match with the "[" and "]"?

[image]

The pictures is seen there. As you can see, I have escaped the [ and ] with .

I do not want it to match with 5B but I want it to match with 5[B]. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `\b` and It will work as expected [DEMO](https://regexr.com/66nvk)

`^(5\[B\])`

[image]

Comment: For a match only, you can omit the capture group `^5\[B]`